# nginx не пропускает русские символы и пробелы

Tags: php, nginx

Английский пропускает а русский нет. ПОдозреваю потому что в русском кодировка через %

Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить пробел и %

```
rewrite ^/([-\w]+)?$ /index.php?p1=$1 last;
```

Comment: ну вот прямо так и написать, внутри квадратных скобок пробел и процент. И еще знак `+` к ним, потому что пробелы в url могут им обозначаться

Answer (score 0):

т.к. ваша регулярка охватывает весь URL от начала и до конца, то предлагаю ее модифицировать так:
`rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?p1=$1 last;`